# The name 'p' does not exist in the current context using javascript in ASP.net mvc

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to pass two parameters to controllers method and alter one parameter using javascript but the other parameter p is inaccessible inside javascript which is declared in body section. Following is the code which i am using. Please give suggestion.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.linkAction').click(function (e) {
                $('.linkAction').attr('href', '@Url.Action("UsersList", "Home", new { page=p,str = "---" })'.replace("---", $('.txtString').val()));
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    @Html.TextBox("Strings", null, new { @class = "txtString" })
    <input type="button" value="filter" id="Button1" />
    <div class="pagination">
        @for ( p = 1; p <= ViewBag.Total; p++)
        {
            <a href="@Url.Action("UsersList", "Home", new { page=p,str = "---" })" class="linkAction">@p</a>
        }
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only replace `---` which you are using as a placeholder

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.linkAction').click(function (e) {
        //redirect with updated parameter
        window.location.href = $(this).attr('href').replace("---", $('.txtString').val());

        //Prevent default action
        return false;
    });
  });
```